# Масштабирование спрайтовых изображений без потери качества

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть изображение, на котором большое количество спрайтов. Я вставляю их с помощью `background: url('') x y`. При **hover'e** на картинку - они должны увеличиваться. Всё так и происходит, но картинка становится мыльной. **Может есть какие-нибудь способы увеличения размеров спрайта без потери качества?**

Comment: код забыли(фылдов)

Comment: @meine, я думаю, тут код не особо нужен. Вопрос достаточно общий

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, добавил

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, вроде неплохой сайт. Спасибо

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко там есть ограничения, так-то он платный, но десяток катринок кажется дает обработать, к слову интерфейс там удобный, в отличии от редакторов

Comment: вот еще js трассировщик, я его использую в онлайн редакторах для перегонки растра в вектор https://github.com/kilobtye/potrace

Comment: однако если не нужны блики, такое проще кодом нарисовать, даже svg подойдет, наверное :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте вместо растровых изображений векторные. Также вместо изображений можно использовать иконочный шрифт.

Comment: То есть конвертировать png картинку в svg?

Comment: @MoloF это не так, я знаю как минимум 2 js библиотеки для этого, и вот например это https://www.vectorizer.io, я уже не говорю о продвинутых редакторах